# jQuery - DataTables - ColumnFilter Doesn't Work

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using DataTables (successfully) and am trying to incorporate ColumnFilter. My JS looks as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    oTable = $('#ecTable').dataTable({
        "sScrollY": "550px",
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "bInfo": true,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "aaSorting": [[0, 'desc']]
    })

    .columnFilter({
        aoColumns: [
            null,
            null,
            { type: "select" },
            { type: "select" },
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null]
    });
});
```

My table header and footer looks like this:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Listing Date</th>
        <th>Expiration Date</th>
        <th>Manufacturer</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Body Style</th>
        <th>Engine</th>
        <th>Year</th>
        <th>Mileage</th>
        <th>Ext. Color</th>
        <th>Int. Color</th>
        <th>Listing Price</th>
        <th>Comments</th>
        <th>Number Of Views</th>
        <th class="noSort">Navigation</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

   <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Listing Date</th>
            <th>Expiration Date</th>
            <th>Manufacturer</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Body Style</th>
            <th>Engine</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Mileage</th>
            <th>Ext. Color</th>
            <th>Int. Color</th>
            <th>Listing Price</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
            <th>Number Of Views</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

I'm not getting any errors in Chrome. The resulting data table looks exactly as it should, except it has no filter columns. Looking at the generated source, the JS for column filter is getting downloaded. Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm no datatables expert, but could this line have something to do with it? `"bFilter": false,`

Comment: @Jules - That was exactly the problem! I had this turned off because I didn't want to use the default DataTables searching. If you create this as an answer, I'll vote it up and accept it.

Comment: thanks :) it can be hard sometimes to spot the obvious in your own code.

Comment: @Jules - I guess it would help if the documentation were better.

Comment: @RandyMinder, if you need only slect filters you can also try out this filter plugin github.com/vedmack/yadcf :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comment promoted to answer:

I'm no datatables expert, but could this line have something to do with it? `"bFilter": false,`